# How to get few random keys from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map with titles. I want to print 10 random keys from my hashmap.

For example my map (String, Object) contains 100 pairs: "A, new Object(...)", "B, ...", "C, ..." etc.

I want to get 10 random keys from this map and append it to one string.

So my string should looks like: "A\nD\nB".

Comment: "Random" or "arbitrary"? Do you want different keys every time with no discernable pattern, or do you just want 10 keys and you don't care which?

Comment: I mean random but unique. Keys should not be repeated.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to get 10 random items out of an ArrayList? That'd be a good place to start.

Comment: I tried with Random and list, but i can get same random numbers and output will be like "A, A, B"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way to get random 10 keys **without repetition** is putting the keys in a list and using `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list.

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...yourmap
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);
List<String> randomTenKeys = keys.subList(0, 10);
```

Creating a list of all keys and shuffling it is not the most efficient thing you can do. You can do it in a single pass with a [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) algorithm. I haven't looked into it but you can probably find an implementation in some Apache or Guava library.

Answer (score 1):

Joni's answer is quite good and short. But, here is a fully working example if you'd like. I split your problem into two methods - one to return a list of randomly selected keys and another to print keys in whichever way you like. You could combine the two methods into one. But, its better to keep them separate.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        //You can use for loop instead to make a map of String, Integer. 
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9).forEach(i -> map.put(i +"", i));//Map of 10 numbers.

        List<String> keys = getRandomKeys(map, 3);
        String allKeys = combineKeys(keys, "\n");
        System.out.println(allKeys);
    }

    public static List<String> getRandomKeys(Map<String, Object> map, int keyCount) {
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());

        for(int i = 0; i < map.size()-keyCount; i++){
            int idx = (int) ( Math.random() *  keys.size() );
            keys.remove(idx);
        }
        return keys;
    }

    public static String combineKeys(List<String> keys, String separator){
        String all = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++){
            all = all + keys.get(i) + separator;
        }

        all += keys.get(keys.size()-1);//last element does not need separator.

        return all;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getRandomKeys` removes `keyCount` keys, and returns `map.size()-keyCount` keys

Comment: @Joni - thanks for finding the bug ! I changed my code and test keyCount to avoid this kind of bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *complementary answer* to [Joni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086200/how-to-get-few-random-keys-from-hashmap/61086596#61086596). Use `String:join` to join the `randomTenKeys`.

Given below is [Joni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086200/how-to-get-few-random-keys-from-hashmap/61086596#61086596):

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...yourmap
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);
List<String> randomTenKeys = keys.subList(0, 10);
```

and the *complementary answer* is:

```
String joinedKeys = String.join("\n", randomTenKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

HashMap Stores the values already in unsorted order it is random.
you can directly use

```
for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet())
    str.append(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
```

however if you want new order every time you can shuffle your data.
For Shuffle you need to get all keys in a array or list
Then you can shuffle that list and iterate over that list to get values from hashmap

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> keys = myMap.keySet();
String combined = "";
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   int random = (int)(Math.random() * keys.size());
   String key = keys.get(random);
   combined += key + "\n";
   keys.remove(random);
}
```

Comment: There is no `Set.get(int)` method.

Comment: If a `Set.get(int)` method did exist, this method would remove entries from the original map because it calls `keys.remove`